# Problem with PWM interference

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, pwm

I have a following code

```
  #include <Servo.h> //library for servo drive
  int MotorAPinA = 9;   //pin number for DC drive
  int MotorAPinB = 10;  //pin number for DC drive
  Servo myservo; //create object myservo, class servo from Servo library

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(MotorAPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorAPinB, OUTPUT);
  //myservo.attach(6); //pin number for servo output
  myservo.write(65);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(MotorAPinA, 240);
}
```

This very code works only partly. 
If I comment line

```
myservo.attach(6)
```

then I got my DC drive working. 
If I uncomment this line, my Servo goings crazy (effect looks like myservo.write(0) constantly), until I comment line

```
analogWrite(MotorAPinA, 240);
```

and then I got my servo working properly. 
While myservo.attach(6) is uncommented, DC drive doesn't work (with uncommented analogWrite).

So, basically, I can have or PWM or Servo working simultaneously, but not both

Any ideas? Arduino Uno R3, Arduino 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your PWM outputs are both on `16b` `Timer/Counter 1` and the servo is attached to the `8b` `Timer/Counter 0`. So my guess is that `8bit` counter has too low resolution for driving the servo and it uses `Timer/Counter 1` in full `16b` mode for better precision instead (PWM uses just `8bits` from 16). Also `Timer/Counter 0` is used for counting millis, so its settings can't be changed anyway.

For the confirmation you can either:

- use pins `5` and `6` (`TC0`) or/and pins `3` and `11` (`TC2`) and for the servo use pin `9` or `10`
- You can read the values of `TC1` configuration registers and according to the datasheet you can figure out what mode is currently used.

EDIT:
So on the Uno board is used Timer/Counter 1 for timing purposes:

```
  if(timer == _timer1) {
    TCCR1A = 0;             // normal counting mode
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS11);     // set prescaler of 8
    TCNT1 = 0;              // clear the timer count
    TIFR |= _BV(OCF1A);      // clear any pending interrupts;
    TIMSK |=  _BV(OCIE1A) ;  // enable the output compare interrupt
    timerAttach(TIMER1OUTCOMPAREA_INT, Timer1Service);
  }
```

So no `PWM` on the `OC1A` nor `OC1B` in normal mode and the channel A is taken by Servo.

Comment: `
#include <Servo.h> //library for servo drive
  int MotorAPinA = 6;   //pin number for DC drive
  int MotorAPinB = 5;  //pin number for DC drive
  Servo myservo; //create object myservo, class servo from Servo library
  
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(MotorAPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorAPinB, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(9); //pin number for servo output
  myservo.write(65);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(MotorAPinA, 240);
  //analogWrite(MotorAPinB, 0);  
}
`
somehow `` doesn't code code

Comment: Now it works. Servo on Timer/Counter1 16 bit (10 and 9 pins), PWMs on Timer/Counter0 0 bit (6 and 5 pins), and there are still free 11 and 3 pins of Timer/Counter2